# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a project for school. That error appears when I tried to add sitemap to my site.

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP._Page__ViewStart_cshtml' to type 'System.Web.WebPages.StartPage'.]
System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.GetStartPage(WebPageRenderingBase page, String fileName, IEnumerable`1 supportedExtensions) +250
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +162
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

I have tried to undo change, and rebuild project, but I still get this error. I have a backup at the last build, the code when I undid and the code from backup are the same, but the backup code does not give me error. Is this a bug?
(My English are not good, sorry)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don not know, if this will help you, but I stumbled upon the same problem when I moved _ViewStart.cshtml away from the Views folder to the root folder of my project. Maybe you have acidentally done the same?

Comment: Yeah, it's exact the problem. Thank you